# Shared variable between consumers and producers in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, ipc, apache-zookeeper

I know consumers and producers are supposed to be agnostic to each other. However, I need the consumer to know if the producer of a given topic is processing a new event (ie computing it). Is there a good way to do this in Kafka? Using a shared variable mechanism? Zookeeper?

If not, do you see any good alternative? I have two ideas in mind:

- IPC, but if producers and consumers do not lie on the same machine, it might be problematic.
- creating my own endpoint when consumers can request the status of a producer.

Small use-case:

I have a time series, x_0, x_1 ... x_n. Where 0, 1 ... n are timestamps.
My service will compute and send data (using a kafka producer) that can take up to several seconds to be computed. The data looks like y_n = f(x_0, x_1 .., x_n), where f is the feed-forward function of a neural network (let's say a big one). When time=n, the consumer polls all the y_t's such that t <= n. So, the consumer has to wait if the service is computing y_n since it is not immediate. For that reason, I would like the consumer to read a flag where it is written "service is computing y_n right now" in order to know if it has to wait or move on.

@update: I am using zookeeper as a key-value data structure where I can store the status of my producers. I am using the python client Kazoo for that.

Comment: Can you please shed light on the use case ?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question on why you need to be aware whether Kafka producer is computing as it depends on multiple factors.

Comment: I have added some details to my questions.

Comment: I realize I might have used the term producer a bit loosely. I need the consumer to know if the SERVICE is computing the new data point (before sending it using a producer).